# Les écouteurs: earbuds, insert earphones and headphones

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs

How does one distinguish between earphones?  There are headphones that sit on your ears, over your ears and those that are called earbuds and then there are insert earphones (slightly different to earbuds).  How does one call these different types of earphones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we use 
**casque** for headphones (we also use *casque* for helmet) 
more precisely: 
**casque à conduction osseuse** for bone conduction headphones 
**casque circum aural** for Circum 
**casque on-ear** for Supra 
we do use the English to make distinction between these types, but it's to be specific, in normal life you will use **casque** 
**écouteurs** for earbuds

I don't see what insert earphones are, maybe **écouteurs intra-auriculaires** if *insert earphones* = earbubs that go deep into the ear

Comment: Sweet.  I was looking for intra-auriculaires.  Boy is that a mouth full.  That describes them perfectly.  Because there is Supra (against ear), Circum (around/over ear) and Intra (inside ear).

Comment: on the other hand, I don't know the french word to make a difference between circum/on-ear headphones. When I was looking to buy one, the english word was used everywhere: **casque circum aural** et **casque on-ear**

Comment: @Flying_whale: j'ai entendu _circum-aural / circum-auriculaire_ pour les casques qui entourent l'oreille et _supra-aural / supra-auriculaire_ pour ceux qui sont juste posés dessus.

Comment: j'ajouterai le "casque à conduction osseuse" (bone conduction headphones) à la liste :)